# Calculated value not showing in custom Display form

Tags: calculated-column, custom-form, display-form

So I have a calculated column that is adding up data from 6 other columns in my list.  The calculation adds up just fine.

However I need to create a custom Display form.  When I create the custom display form the calculate column does not appear in the view.  So I created some XML code to get the column to display.  I get the column to appear just fine, however the calculated value does not appear. I am wondering if Javascript is required to get the value to display properly.  I have disable-output-escaping in the code here, but taking it away or adding it does not get the value to display at all.

```
                <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Total Score</nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@SPFieldCalculated" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I have also included pictures of what displays when this code is entered and what my code looks like in the default display form.

Thank you for any help.

[image: Original Display form code]

[image]

**EDIT: While I have @SPFieldCalculated listed in my code, I have also attempted to use @SPBookmark_Total_x0020_Score to no avail.  This was just a test to see what the change of the select tag would do.**